# Decorator after @task decorator in celery

Tags: python, celery, decorator, django-celery

I'm trying to apply a decorator after the celery @task decorator, something like.

```
@send_email
@task
def any_function():

   print "inside the function"
```

I can get it to work in the way it is recommended in the docs, i.e. to put the decorator before the task decorator, but in this case I would like to access the task instance in my decorator.

The @send_email would have to be a class decorator, this is what I tried without success:

```
class send_email(object):
    ''' wraps a Task celery class '''
    def __init__(self, obj):

        self.wrapped_obj = obj

        functools.update_wrapper(self, obj)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        print "call"

        return self.wrapped_obj.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):

        print "run"

        return self.wrapped_obj.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):

        if attr in self.__dict__:

            return getattr(self, attr)

        return getattr(self.wrapped_obj, attr)
```

I can never get the print statement in the **call** or run function function to appear in either the worker or the caller.

How can we decorate a celery Task, without resorting to class-based task definitions (so the decorator would be above @task above a function definition.

Thanks for any help!

Miguel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The task decorator does not return a class, it returns an instance.

It seems that your question should really be "How can I have access to the task inside the decorator" rather than how you can apply the decorator first.

In the upcoming 3.1 (development version) you can use bound tasks to accomplish this:

```
def send_email(fun):
    @wraps(fun)
    def outer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated and task is {0!r}'.format(self))
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return outer

@task(bind=True)
@send_email
def any_function(self):
    print('inside the function')
```

For previous versions you can use `current_task`:

```
from celery import current_task

def send_email(fun):

    @wraps(fun)
    def outer(*args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated and task is: %r' % (current_task, ))
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)

    return outer

@task
@send_email
def any_function():
    print('inside the function')
```

Comment: Can anyone explain what {0!r} is doing?  After searching a while, I found this in the Python docs:  '!r' (apply repr()) can be used to convert the value before it is formatted.  But the definition of what repr() does seems vague. Thanks,

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts All objects have two different ways to present itself[1]: `str(obj)` (which calls `obj.__str__()`) is usually used for display in user interfaces and so on, then there is `repr(obj)` (calls `obj.__repr__()`) which is used for debugging purposes and often prints the type of the object, the memory location of the object and important attributes. In a format string `"{0!s}"` is the former and `"{0!r}"` is the latter, and in the old formats they are `"%s"` and `"%r"` respectively.  [1]: There are three in Python2: ``__unicode__``, ``__str__`` and ``__repr__``.

Comment: I am trapped in a slightly different situation. Considering this question what If I want to do some db operation at the start, end of `any_function`. Also I want to be able to do another db operation upon exception in `any_function`. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

"before" looks like "after" visually.

Eg, this:

```
@decorator1
@decorator2
@decorator3
def func():
  pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def func():
  pass

func = decorator1(decorator2(decorator3(func)))
```

This means you have to write `@send_email` after `@task` to get it applied before `@task`. Eg:

```
@task
@send_email
def any_function():
    print "inside the function"
```

Comment: I want it to be applied after @task, the problem is that \@task returns a class